# Building XML from a Python structure

Tags: python, xml

is it possible to build an XML string from a Python structure (e.g. nested lists, dictionaries, etc.) or it is a non-sense question?

Is there any standard tool?

Thanks

Comment: these nested list of dictionary contains tags of value?

Comment: If you just want to save some Python objects, use pickle. Anything fully general for arbitary Python objects would end up very Python-specific so you might as well use pickle. If you want interop with some other language, you have to know which data formats (not just "XML" but the exact schema) you can support on the other ends as well, and you need to tell us so we can tell you which ones are supported by Python as well.

Comment: I need XML to save data for MS Project and I was looking for something better than raw string building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need some custom format, you can use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to programatically generate such a format. For example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def dict2xml(d, parent=None):
    if parent is None:
        parent = ElementTree.Element('xml')

    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, str):
            element = ElementTree.SubElement(parent, key)
            element.text = value
    elif isinstance(value, dict):
            element = ElementTree.SubElement(parent, key)
            dict2xml(value, element)
    elif isinstance(value, list):
            for text in value:
            element = ElementTree.SubElement(parent, key)
            element.text = str(text)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Unexpected value type: {0}'
                            .format(type(value)))


    return parent

d = {'a': 'a contents',
     'b': {'c': 'c contents',
           'd': 'd contents',
           },
     'e': range(3),
     }

print ElementTree.tostring(dict2xml(d))
```

Generates the following output:

```
<xml><a>a contents</a><b><c>c contents</c><d>d contents</d></b><e>0</e><e>1</e><e>2</e></xml>
```

Comment: I do not know much about XML, but I think that this solution suites my needs: is it quite general to be used also for future needs?

Comment: @Don Yes, you can expand it in the future, for example, to define attributes for tags.

Answer (score 4):

There is no object-to-XML serialization in the standard library, but there is [pyxser](http://coder.cl/products/pyxser/).